Launching a flask application using Gunicorn leads to Internal Server Error
I am having a problem when trying to launch my Flask application on a VPS using Caddy and Gunicorn.
I initially thought the problem was in Caddy and in the setup of Caddyfile, since I believed that my application is running properly using Gunicorn, but apparently it is not.
I am trying to run the app in these steps :
source env/bin/activate
cd project
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 app:application --daemon

then, when I test, to is if it is returning me the webpage I expect with a basic curl command
curl 127.0.0.1:8000
I get
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Internal Server Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><p>Internal Server Error</p></h1>

  </body>
</html>

ps aux | grep gunicorn
root        3029  0.0  0.9  33888 19860 ?        S    14:49   0:00 /root/env/bin/python3 /root/env/bin/gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 app:application --daemon
root        3030  0.0  1.6  46196 32980 ?        S    14:49   0:00 /root/env/bin/python3 /root/env/bin/gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 app:application --daemon
root        3056  0.0  0.1   6544  2304 pts/0    S+   15:01   0:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn

final lines of app.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port='8888')

I believe that all dependencies were installed correctly.
I have tried changing the ports in the Gunicorn command

Do the logs show you why there's an internal server error?

Why are you binding 2 different addresses and 2 different ports?
